# Plotting a function

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a function (the hill function) when `X` and `K` are the same (`x==k`) the output should be `0.5`, when I test the function it gives a result of `0.5`, when I try to plot it, I do not get `0.5` for my `Y`. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

```
n = 1;
k = 1;
x = [0:0.01:2].';

y = (x.^n)/((x.^n)+(k.^n));
plot(x,y);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
n = 1;
k = 1;
x = [0:0.01:2].';

y = (x.^n)./((x.^n)+(k.^n));
plot(x,y);
```

[image]

You missed a dot before the division.